# I am having this error Clearing text not successful. Attempting to clear by selecting all and deleting

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, testng, appium

I am running an Appium TestNG automation mobile testing test on android app. My test case is for login. Once it fills the userid it deletes and retype twice and same for the password also which makes it unable to login.

Please see the part of the log which is troubling me.

```
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: setText
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using element passed in: 3
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Attempting to clear using UiObject.clearText().
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Clearing text not successful. Attempting to clear by selecting all and deleting.
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Clearing text not successful. Attempting to clear by sending delete keys.
```

BasePage.java:

```
package com.mobile.pages;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

/**
 * Base class for the test case screens. All the pages to extend this base class.

public class BasePage {

    /**
     * Variable of type {@link AppiumDriver}
     */
    protected AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Constructor for the class.
     * 
     * @param driver
     */
    public BasePage(AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

LoginPage.java:

```
package com.mobile.pages;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;    
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;    
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.commands.WaitForCondition;

public class LoginPage extends BasePage {

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Allow permissions button.
     */
    @FindBy(id="com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")
    private MobileElement allowPermissions;
    /**
     * User id input text field.
     */
    @FindBy(id="com.dealermanagementportal:id/et_username")
    private MobileElement userId;
    /**
     * Password input text field.
     */
    @FindBy(id="com.dealermanagementportal:id/et_password")
    private MobileElement password;
    /**
     * Button to be clicked for login.
     */
    @FindBy(id="com.dealermanagementportal:id/btn_login")
    private MobileElement loginButton;
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Constructor of the class.
     * @param driver
     */
    public LoginPage(AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Method to do login.
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public boolean doLogin(String p_user_id, String p_password, String p_messg) throws InterruptedException {
        /*WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,600);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")));*/

        allowPermissions.click();
        allowPermissions.click();

        userId.sendKeys(p_user_id); 
        password.sendKeys(p_password);
        loginButton.click();            
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        DashboardPage dashboard = new DashboardPage(driver);
        return dashboard.getWelcomeText().getText().startsWith(p_messg);

    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public MobileElement getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public MobileElement getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public MobileElement getLoginButton() {
        return loginButton;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

DashboardPage.java

```
package com.mobile.pages;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;    
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class DashboardPage extends BasePage {

    /**
     * Welcome message displayed on dashboard.
     */
    @FindBy(id="com.dealermanagementportal:id/tv_welcome_user_txt")
    private MobileElement welcomeText;
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Constructor of the class.
     * 
     * @param driver
     */
    public DashboardPage(AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public MobileElement getWelcomeText() {
        return welcomeText;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

BaseTestConfig.java:

```
package com.mobile.testcases;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;    
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;    
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

/**
 * Base class for All Test Cases. All the test cases to extend this base class.

public abstract class BaseTestConfig {

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Instance of {@link WebDriver}
     */
    protected AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
    /**
     * Instance of {@link AppiumDriverLocalService}
     */
    private AppiumDriverLocalService appiumService;
    /**
     * Variable to store appium service url.
     */
    private String appiumServiceUrl;
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Method to be called before start of the test suite. This method will launch the appium server installed on the 
     * machine. This method will load the device capabilites configuration and launch the device using appium.
     */
    @BeforeSuite
    public void doBeforeSuite() {
        appiumService = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
        appiumService.start();
        appiumServiceUrl = appiumService.getUrl().toString();

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("device_capabilities.properties"));

            Map<String, String> prop_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (String key : prop.stringPropertyNames()) {
                prop_map.put(key, prop.getProperty(key));
            }           
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(prop_map);
            driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(appiumServiceUrl), capabilities);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Method to be called before the test starts. All the extending class to implement this method as per the test case requirements.
     */
    @BeforeTest
    public abstract void doBeforeTest();
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Method to be called after the test case execution. All the extending class to implement this method as per the test case requirements.
     */
    @AfterTest
    public abstract void doAfterTest();
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Method to be called after test suite execution to close the web driver and close the appium service.
     */
    @AfterSuite
    public void doAfterSuite() {
        driver.quit();
        appiumService.stop();
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Login.java:

```
package com.mobile.testcases;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;    
import com.mobile.pages.LoginPage;
import com.mobile.testdata.TestDataProvider;

public class Login extends BaseTestConfig {

    /**
     * Variable of type {@link LoginPage}
     */
    private LoginPage page;
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @BeforeTest
    @Override
    public void doBeforeTest() {
        page = new LoginPage(driver);
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Test(dataProvider="loginTestData", dataProviderClass=TestDataProvider.class)
    public void testLogin(String userId, String password, String messg) throws InterruptedException {
        Assert.assertTrue(page.doLogin(userId, password, messg));
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @AfterTest
    @Override
    public void doAfterTest() {

    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

TestDataProvider.java

```
package com.mobile.testdata;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

/**
 * This class to act as data provider for the test cases.

public class TestDataProvider {

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * This method to generate test data for Login test case. It will return an array of array, where the array consists of
     * three fields, first the user id, second user password, and third the post login message value to be validated.
     * @return
     */
    @DataProvider(name="loginTestData")
    public static Object[][] loginData(){
        return new Object[][]{
                { "admin", "123", "Welcome" }
        };
    }

}
```

device_capabilities.properties:

```
deviceName=Android Emulator
platformName=Android
deviceReadyTimeout=20
appWaitPackage=com.dealermanagementportal
appWaitDuration=60000
avd=Nexus_5X_API_23
app=D:\\app.apk
appPackage=com.dealermanagementportal
appActivity=com.dealermanagementportal.login.WelcomeFragmentActivity
```

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using?

Comment: Hi Anish, I have provided the codes. Hope it will help you to understand.